# Format Logstash output to a plain text pattern

Tags: logstash

I want Logstash to output to Papertrail log service, how can I transform logstash output to this plain text pattern? :

```
<22>1 2014-06-18T09:56:21Z sendername programname - - - the log message
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out using `logstash-output-syslog` plugin:

```
output {
  syslog {
    host => ...
    port => ...
    protocol => "tcp"
    codec => "plain"
    facility => "user-level"
    severity => "notice"
    rfc => "rfc5424"
  }
}
```